# Is the language of Turing Machines that halt on every input recognizable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability, halting-problem

I  am trying to reduce the complement of the HALTING problem (WLOG, the complement of the HALTING problem is the language of TMs that loop on some string w)to this language in order to show that it is not recognizable. Does anyone know how to do this reduction, what I come up with is:

Using python-like syntax:

```
def R(<M>,w):
    def F(x):
        if M(w)loops: //Run M on w
            return True on every x
        else
            loop on every x
return F
```

Of course the problem here is that we can't really know when M loops on w

Does anyone know how to do this reduction, or if it is possible to prove that the language of TMs that accept every input string is unrecognizable using a reduction from a different unrecognizable language?

Comment: I am afraid that a TM that does not halt is not necessarily looping. That is true only of memory bounded automata.

Comment: @babou "Not halting" is often called "looping" even though the machine may move to new tape cells all the time.

Comment: Using closure properties is easier here. (What happens if a language and its complement are both recognizable?)

Comment: @Raphael Regarding "looping".  I will take your word for it. But I will still consider it a poor practice as it may cause confusion between two very distinct concepts.

Comment: Hint: you are doing the reduction the wrong way around. Assume that your new language was semi-decidable and build a machine/algorithm for the complement of HALTING using it.

Comment: @Raphael do you mean I should reduce my new language to the complement of HALTING?

Comment: No, your text is the wrong way around, but I think your function tries to do the other direction. (Maybe I brainfarted.)

Comment: if it existed it could immediately resolve [collatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) & many other open conjectures...

Comment: @vzn That's not an issue at all, since existence does not mean we know it.

Answer (score 10):

**Preliminary**

Let $H$ be the usual halting language:
$$
H=\{(\langle M\rangle, w)\mid M(w) \text{ halts}\}
$$
Its complement is
$$
\overline{H}=\{(\langle M\rangle, w)\mid M(w) \text{ doesn't halt}\}
$$
We know that $H$ is recognizable (just run $M$ on $w$ and do what it does), so $\overline{H}$ must be unrecognizable (otherwise $H$ would be decidable, which we know isn't true).

**The Reduction**

As you suggested, we'll produce a reduction from $\overline{H}$ to
$$
AH = \{\langle N\rangle\mid N \text{ halts on all }x\}
$$
thus showing that $AH$ is unrecognizable. As you suggested, what we want is to map $(\langle M\rangle, w)$ to a description of a TM $M_w$ where

```
Mw(x) =
   run M on w
   if M(W) halts
      loop
   if M(w) doesn't halt
      halt
```

That would do it, except for the fact that if $M$ didn't halt on $w$, we'd never get to the $\texttt{halt}$ instruction. What we need is a *finite* way of testing for non-halting. A standard way to deal with this kind of difficulty is to limit the number of steps our simulation will perform, like this:

```
N(x) =
   run M on w for |x| steps
   if M has halted
      loop
   if M(w) hasn't halted yet
      halt
```

How does this modification help us?

- If $(\langle M\rangle, w)\in\overline{H}$, then $M(w)$ will never halt, so $N(x)$ will halt after $|\,x\,|$ steps and thus $\langle N\rangle\in AH$
- If $(\langle M\rangle, w)\notin\overline{H}$ then $M(w)$ will eventually halt, say after $s$ steps. This means that $N$ will halt on all inputs, $x$ of length less than $s$, and will loop on all longer inputs, so $\langle N\rangle\notin AH$.

This establishes the reduction we needed, and so we can conclude that $AH$ is non-recognizable.

Comment: I have an issue with this answer. What happens if $<M>$ is the Turing machine: Read all the input $x$, then do another step to the right, and then halt?
On one hand, it will never halt after $|x|$ steps, therefore $N(x)$ will halt for all inputs, but $(<M>, x)\notin\overline{H}$ for any word $X$.

Comment: @Nescio For all words $x$ that are fed to $N$ **by the supposed machine that recognizes AH**, $M$ will be run on **its own fixed word $w$**. Think of $x$ not as a word, but as a counter which the machine $M$ cannot access.