# Turing machine that does not halt on any input

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

I'm struggling to find a way to show that 
$$T = \{ \langle M \rangle\mid M \text{does not halt on any input}\}$$
is undecidable.
Should I use reduction? If so, reduce this to what &ndashp the halting problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use reduction, you would need to show that the halting problem reduces $T$, not the other way around.

The reduction<sup>*</sup> in this case is a standard one. You want to know if $M$ halts on input $w$ but all you have is <strike>this lousy T-shirt</strike> a procedure that tells you if a machine loops on every input. So you construct a machine $M'$ such that does the same thing on every input, so that whether or not $M'\in T$ tells you whether or not $M$ halts on input $w$.

<sup>* Well, strictly *a* reduction: if there's one, there are infinitely many.</sup>

Comment: So i have to build $M'$ to solve the halting problem using $T$ right? How can i "make sure that thing tells you what $M$ does on input $w$", im sorry i dont really understand how to do this :(

Comment: Not quite. You have to build $M'$ from $M$ and $w$ so that whether or not $M'\in T$ tells you whether or not $M(w)$ halts$.

Comment: If $M' \in T$ then $M(w)$ doesnt halt. The thing i dont understand is how i go about the "any input" thing compared to having a $w$ or $w\#w$. Is it possible to say that $M'$ tests all possible inputs??

Comment: $M'$ doesn't need to test all inputs, because you only care about input $w$. Have you seen the proof that "Does this TM halt on every input?" is undecidable? The proof you need here is almost identical.

Comment: you mean https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/39651/is-the-language-of-turing-machines-that-halt-on-every-input-recognizable?

Comment: @idontunderstandthis Yes. That's asking a slightly different problem (showing that a language isn't even RE, let alone decidable) but, if you understand what's there, you should be able to answer your question.

Comment: So $M'$ writes $w$ and then simulates $M(w)$, if $M(w)$ halts that means $M' {\not \in}T$ and it rejects, otherwise it accepts?

Comment: Almost, but you're doing the reduction the wrong way around. You're supposed to use whether or not $M'\in T$ to decide whether $M$ halts (reducing the halting problem to $T$, which shows that $T$ is undecidable because the halting problem is), not using whether or not $M$ halts to decide whether $M'\in T$ (reducing $T$ to the halting problem, which just shows that $T$ isn't any harder than the halting problem, while leaving open the possibility that it might be easier). But $M'\notin T$ if and only if $M(w)$ halts, so you don't need to do any more work; just write the answer the right way. :-)